# libcublas.so.8.0 not found even it exists

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, cublas

simple problem here:

When trying to import tensorflow i get this:

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Even though i can locate the file:

```
sudo find / -name 'libcublas.so.8.0'
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcublas.so.8.0
```

What i have installed already:

```
Python 3.5.2
Cuda 8.0
cuDNN v.6
nvidia-384
```

Paths:

```
echo $CUDA_HOME - /usr/local/cuda
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH - /usr/local/cuda/lib64
echo $PATH /home/laimonas-sutkus/Projects/idenfy_ivs/environments/tensorflow/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/laimonas-sutkus/bin:/home/laimonas-sutkus/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

OS (Can't use ubuntu since it crashes if i install gpu drivers):

```
Linux Mint 18.3
```

Comment: `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` isn't `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64`, create a symlink maybe

Comment: Yeah, there was a symlink by default when installed cuda.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that is a very stupid mistake.

Make sure in your .bashrc file you have these exact lines (only if you have used the default installation locations):

```
export CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/cuda/lib64'

# Override PATH
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```